# Need SQLQuery with Stored procedure with below example

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have the following MySQL-table

```
Id  |  One  |  Two  |  Three
----------------------------
1   |  10   |  30   |  20
2   |  50   |  60   |  20
3   |  60   |  0    |  40
```

the average must be using stored procedure, not normal query.

I have normal SQL Query

```
select id, (ifnull(one,0) + ifnull(two,0) + ifnull(three,0))/
  ((one is not null) + (two is not null) + (three is not null)) as average from table
```

I want that to look like this, with a MySQL query:

```
Id | Average
------------
1  | 20
2  | 43.3
3  | 50
```

Comment: i am poor in English sorry if not understand check the image in question

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot make use of an image of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Stu Sorry for my English now i clear pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Id`'s on your table are unique, you can do it like this (you were pretty close... just the `case when` was missed in your query):

```
select 
  Id, 
  (ifnull(one,0) + ifnull(two,0) + ifnull(three,0))/ 
  (
    (case when one is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
    (case when two is not null then 1 else 0 end) + 
    (case when three is not null then 1 else 0 end) 
  ) as average
from {your_table}
```

You can test on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=6670135789a69cc75fbb1a9eade139c3)

Comment: Thanks for your support. I need Query using Stored procedure.. how can declare variable and all..?

Comment: You are welcome. If answer is correct please set it.

Comment: using stored procedure i need just normal query i can... pls how we do in stored procedure?